# SAPUI5: External Libraries in Extension

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I try to add an external library to my UI5 project. In my case it **jsPDF** but it could be any.
I add it to the **manifest.json** like this:

```
"js": [{
            "uri": "libs/jspdf.js"
        }
```

If I try to do

```
var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt");
```

afterwards, it works fine in a standalone UI5 application but not in an extension.
If I check **window** in my running application it doesn't have **jsPDF**.
I also tried to add it using `sap.ui.define` with the same result.
What am I missing? Is there another way to add libraries to extensions? Or is it added but not to **window** but somewhere else?

Comment: Did you check in developer tools and ensure that jspdf.js was actually loaded? Most probably it was not loaded at all or there was a 404.

Comment: Yes it is loaded. That's not the problem.

Comment: Have you read this blog post? Especially that you should not use the global lib name in the define function: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/30/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-modules-in-sapui5/

Comment: Yep, I read a lot of blogs. It's not a general problem. Like I said it works fine in standalone apps. There must be something special about extensions

Comment: I cannot think of anything unique to the extension UI5 projects. They are very similar to standalone ui5 projects, just that they are inheriting the component of the parent app.

Answer (score 0):

use this third party library

```
 <script src="path/to/jspdf.min.js">
    onExportPDF: function() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        var source = document. getElement ById ('yourTableId'); // Replace 'yourTableId' with the ID of your table
    
        pdf. fromHTML (source, 15, 15);
        pdf. save('table_export.pdf');
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).